# Is it possible to create a Google App Engine application without Maven / Gradle?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-11

I created a very simple web server using `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` bundled in jdk11,
and I do not have any dependencies so I don't even want to create a pom or gradle build file.

In Google Cloud Run, I can do it with a simple Dockerfile compiling *.java and just execute it.
1 java source file & 1 Dockerfile do the job like below:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", exchange -> {
            byte[] result = "Hello World!".getBytes();
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, result.length);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write(result);
        });
        server.start();
    }
}
```

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
COPY Main.java /home/Main.java
WORKDIR /home/
RUN javac Main.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "Main"]
```

Is it possible to achieve in App Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an executable JAR locally, and deploy that.

Please refer to more details on the link below:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/testing-and-deploying-your-app#other_deployment_options

Comment: Sorry for my misleading question. I'm asking for App Engine but not Cloud Run.
I can easily deploy source to Cloud Run and it is great, so I want to figure it out can I do the same in App Engine

Comment: You can build an executable JAR locally, and deploy that, but guess you aren't looking for that.

Comment: Create a shell script to build jar & deploy seems to be a nice solution. I didn't notice that we can deploy jar directly. May you edit the answer then I can accept it?